# Find or calculate intersection points of a straight line with a diagonal scatter plot using VBA

Tags: vba, intersection

I am trying to understand how I can go about finding or calculating the intersection points of a straight line and a diagonal scatter plot. Just to give a better idea, on an X,Y plot, if I have a straight horizontal line at y= # (any number), that crosses an array of scatters points (which form a diagonal line), how can I calculate points of intersection the two lines?

The problem that I am having is that the scattered array has multiple points around my horizontal line, what I would like to do is find the point that hits the horizontal line first, and the point that hits the horizontal line the last.

please refer to the image for a better understanding. The two points that are annotated are the ones that I am trying to extract with VBA. Is this possible? The image shows two sets of scattered arrays, I am only interested in figuring out the method for 1 of the arrays. If I can extract this for 1 scattered array, I can replicate the method for the next one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qL2wo.jpg

Comment: It would be nice to see some data in an excel sheet. Have you tried any coding before?

Comment: you will need to loop over your raw data for the scatterplot, looking for pairs of consecutive points which span the horizontal line: from each pair found you can calculate an intersect.  Once you have all of the intersects you'd pick out the ones with the highest and lowest x-values.

Comment: @TimWilliams I lost you at the part where I have to check if two points span the horizontal line, what exactly do you mean by this? Would I be using If statements to find points that fall around the horizontal way? or is there a precise way of finding out when a point crosses my horizontal line?

Comment: @Tom I have recently started learning VBA and have started coded, I can recognize the purpose of some VBA code and I can use other resources to understand things that are unknown. The data that needs to be analyzed is already in excel to begin with if that helps

Comment: Yes - you will have to look at the source data for those lines on your scatter plot, and `If` is going to be part of that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you any specifics without knowing the structure of your Data. But this is the approach I'd use.

I'll assume your data looks like this (for both of the plots)

```
A    B
x1   y1
x2   y2
x3   y3
```

Loop through the axis like so:

```
'the y values need to be as high as the black axis you've got there
'I'll assume that's zero

i = 0
k = .Cells(1,1)
'we begin at the first x-value in your column

for i = 0 to Worksheets("Sheet name").UsedRange.Rows.Count
'now we are looking for the lowest value of x, k will be this value

if .Cells(i,1) < k Then 
  if .cells(i,2) = 0 Then '0 = y-value of the "black" axis
   k = .Cells(i,1)
  End If
End If


'every time we find a lower value than our existing k
'we will assign it to k

Next
```

The lowest value will be your "low limit"-point.

You can use that same kind of algorithm for the highest value of the same scatter plot (just change the "<" to ">" or the lowest and highest value for the one, just change the Column ID.

HTH

Comment: you method does not isolate points that lie around the intersection of the two lines. I can find the lowest K value and the highest K value, but they are never at the point of intersection.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, the y-value must be the y-value of your x-axis.